# Можно ли без js заставить юзера заполнить хотя бы одно (любое,но не обязательно все) текстовое поле?

Tags: html, html5

Допустим,есть группа полей:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" />
<input type="text" id="text2" />
<input type="text" id="text3" />
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
```

Можно ли средствами html сделать так, чтобы форма, когда все поля пусты, не отправлялась, а когда хотя бы одно (или больше) заполнено - отправлялась? Ведь для `type="radio"` атрибут `required` работает не так,как для других типов input.. Можно ли его заставить как-то изменить поведение, или может быть есть какой-нибудь такой редкий атрибут типа `required-group` ?

Comment: на бэкенде задачу не решить?

Comment: Решить то можно,хоть на бэке,хоть на фронте, хоть на флеше. Но вопрос не в том

Comment: именно в том. Если у вас есть доступ к бэку, лучше на бэке. нет возможности - будем выкручиваться исходя из данных вещей.

Comment: Если вопрос не в том, то перепишите тему на ту, которая поставила бы вопрос верно.

Comment: Просто интересно: а что задача такая, что даже js использовать нельзя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На чистом HTML5 это реализовать невозможно. Атрибут [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) применяется к одному конкретному `input`'у и не затрагивает другие элементы. Других атрибутов, способных осуществлять валидацию на основании описанных вами правил, у `input`'а [нет](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp). Поэтому либо вы используете JavaScript (проверка на хотя бы одно заполненное поле из списка не слишком сложная), либо валидируете на сервере.

Вы упомянули в качестве примера `<input type="radio"/>`. Это плохой пример, так как логика работы `radio` отличается от логики работы простого `input`'а. В частности, несколько элементов `radio`, имеющие одно имя, рассматриваются как один как с точки зрения отправки значения на сервер при submit'е формы, так и с точки зрения валидации `required`. Для текстовых `input`'ов такой фокус не проходит, даже если вы создадите несколько текстовых `input`'ов с одинаковыми именами, валидация `required` будет применяться к каждому отдельно.